# Hide field based on date field on access form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I would like to hide a text field based on a date field on an access form. The use will enter a date in the field when they leave, but blank if they are current. I display two dates for years of service (current and after they leave).

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
   If IsNull(DateEnd) Then
    Me.YearsOfSeriviceEND.Visible = False
   Else
    Me.YearsOfSeriviceEND.Visible = True
 End If
```

This does not hide the field, YearsOfSeriviceEND.  I'm not sure if this is not working because the field is a date?

Dennis

Comment: Did You try to put breakpoint on the first line and check values?

Comment: Has nothing to do with field type unless it is a text type and field is actually empty string instead of Null. The code should work. But be aware that if form is Continuous, textbox in every record will show the same result. Consider using Conditional Formatting and set Enable/Disable state instead.

Comment: The value is Empty on the (DateEnd) on breakpoint.  It's a single form.  I did a test with two unbound text boxes and the above code does work for that.  I did a breakpoint and the value was Null on that.

Comment: I accidentally put the wrong variable in for the end date.  It should have been EndDate, not DateEnd.  So, once I changed it, it worked.